# compile android_sensors_driver

Tags: android-core, rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to compile android_sensors_driver.

i am using this guide:

https://github.com/chadrockey/android_sensors_driver

i have ubuntu 14.0.4.

ros indigo installed.

rosjava installed

android_core installed.

i am adding android_sensors_driver at android_core folder:

git clone https://github.com/chadrockey/android_sensors_driver.git

edit  the settings.gradle in android_core

and add this line at the end of the file:

include "android_sensors_driver"

then:

cd android_sensors_driver

../gradlew clean debug

then i get error msg:

http://en.textsave.org/UCtb

the build.gradle file:
http://en.textsave.org/YCtb

can you help me compile?

thanks,
Tal.

---

I am master student, working on ros and rosjava project.

I was using android_sensors_driver from android store, and it was great.

I want to modified android_sensors_driver, and re-compile it.

I compiled all the other libraries: rosjava, and android core, with catkin_make (catkin build system).

I change build.gradle at android_sensor_driver, and now it find all the dependencies:

http://en.textsave.org/bEtb

but still, it not fully compile.

and if you can look the errors that i get after modified the build.gradle:

http://en.textsave.org/aEtb

can you help me please?

I feel i am so close, but need the final touch.

Thanks for your time,

Tal Regev.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197420/compile-android_sensors_driver/) by [Tal](https://answers.ros.org/users/11486/tal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 108 on 2014-11-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I talk with Chad Rockey,

he say that the android sensors driver was outdated.

So I modified the project, and now it compile!!

The project now on my github project:

https://github.com/talregev/android_sensors_driver

also update on github of Chad.

---

Originally posted by [Tal](https://answers.ros.org/users/11486/tal/) with karma: 108 on 2014-11-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahariharan](https://answers.ros.org/users/27119/ahariharan/) on 2016-06-09**:
I'm having the same issue but I can't access that repo. Can I please use your modified version ?

**Comment by [Tal](https://answers.ros.org/users/11486/tal/) on 2016-06-09**:
Just download the app from here:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.ros.android.android_all_sensors_driver

**Comment by [Yousof](https://answers.ros.org/users/29342/yousof/) on 2018-08-07**:
Can you update the app link? I cannot find an app that publishes images

**Comment by [Arpit_Patel](https://answers.ros.org/users/55805/arpit_patel/) on 2020-07-01**:
Can you upload new Link this is broken now